# Unable to run cypress test.spec.js file from Cypress Integration folder path

Tags: visual-studio-code, cypress

[image]

I'm new to Cypress and using Visual Studio Code as IDE for Cypress. I have written sample test to launch a web page as below and it has written under Cypress Integration folder.

```
/// <reference types="cypress"/> 

it('Page should navigate to todoMVC', () =>{
    cy.visit('http://todomvc-app-for-testing.surge.sh/')
})
```

If try to run this script from Visual Studio Code terminal using

```
npx cypress open
```

from Integration folder. Cypress window appears after but newly created xx.spec.js file won't be displayed and no error also. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you're running `npx cypress open` from the `cypress/integration` directory.  You should be running this from the root of your project - in your case it would be `C:\VSCode-win32-x64-1.40.0\Code-Work`

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and why every time Integration folder is getting generated with multiple folder tree structure? If run 3 times then 3 levels integration folder getting created with parent integration folder 

Comment: I think they didn't get enough time to test the testing tool itself ;). Its not just running from cypress/integration, even you can't "open" from the "cypress" folder. The spec folder magically ignore anything other than their original shipped samples. even I tried to place the files under the "example" folder but not reflecting in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Go to package.json file of your project, under script write `"cypress":"cypress open"` and then from terminal - `npm run cypress`.
Look here - https://www.opencodez.com/software-testing/front-end-automation-testing-cypress.htm